# HERE Street Basemap in ArcGIS

Tags: api, rest, arcgis, esri, wms

I am having one helluva time getting the new API version of the HERE Street Base Map - aka normal.day to work in ArcGIS.  It fails to take my password even though I logged into HERE Developers site with that same password to create an API key.  Anyone have a quick tutorial?